# Request Timed Out error when JSon Call

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, rest

I've created a JSon Object with Newtonsoft. When I want to pass it to restful webservice and want to response from it, I get "request timed out" error, although I set Timeout for request is -1 or any. Where can be the problem?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://app.myservice.com/sendJSon");
    request.ContentType = "text/json";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Timeout = 200000;

    JObject asnInfo = CreateAsnInfo();

    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, asnInfo);
        }
    }
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy? The code seems to work with a public test web service.

[Link to .NET Fiddle working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RBCHwg)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
        request.ContentType = "text/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Timeout = 200000;

        JObject asnInfo = JObject.Parse(@"{ title: 'foo', body: 'bar', userId: 1 }");

        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, asnInfo);
            }
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine(responseText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran it on localhost. Your sample is working fine. But still I've time out problem for my code.

Comment: In addition, I tested my sample in .NET Fiddle like you. The result is:

Run-time exception (line -1): Execution time limit was exceeded

Stack Trace:

[DotNetFiddle.Infrastructure.LimitExceededException: Execution time limit was exceeded]

Comment: What is the URL you are using in `WebRequest.Create("...")`? Make sure it's a valid URL that is publicly accessible. It would really help if you could share your entire .NET Fiddle.